# Changing from database mirroring to transaction log shipping

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mirroring, log-shipping

I'm considering dumping database mirroring and go with transaction log shipping on our SQL Server 2008 Standard server instead, because there's a noticeable performance hit due to the principal being a beefier machine.

Is it non-trivial to do?

I am guessing I just need to break the synchronization, bring them offline and then configure for log shipping, or will I have to perform a new RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY? Is this correct?

Other things I should keep in mind?

Preferably I'd like asynchronous mirroring but the Enterprise license is a bit much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is pretty straight forward in setting up, you shouldnt have to offline the databases either.  you can actually begin setting up the transaction log shipping before even needing to break the mirror.

for more info here is the SQL dev center link;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895393.aspx

best,
Nick

Comment: That's reassuring, thanks. I'll also have to stop the transaction log backups I'm guessing, or the log chain will be broken?

Comment: yes for sure otherwise the shipping will be inconsistent.